# Is there any reason why American judges would be less capable of speaking English than British judges?

Tags: united-states, lawyer, judge, legal-education, law-school

Every time I see video clips of judges sentencing very grave and dramatic crimes in the U.S., I seem to be struck by how ineloquent and sloppy with their language the judges are. They seem fully competent over their subject matter like the relevant factors to be considered at sentencing and they seem to be very clued up on the ins and outs in the present case, but they also seem to have embarrassing levels of unsophistication when it comes to general English language. I mean things like “all intensive purposes” and seemingly limited vocabulary. For example see this clip at 1:07 and then at 1:20: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mDD8flMdwTg&t=67s

On the other hand in all of my experience, English judges even those hearing comparatively mundane or petty matters seem to always be quite eloquent and sophisticated when it comes to their use of English to express themselves and discharge their judicial duties.

Is the us legal educational system extremely specialised at the expense of general English proficiency? What else could be responsible for this observation?

Comment: US judges sound down to earth, British judges sound pompous. It's not just the judges, either, in my experience. I'm guessing you have the opposite experience. I guess we have different views of our respective dialects. In general, everybody else's dialect is defective.

Comment: @TylerDurden Your perception seems very atypical too me.

Comment: It's possible that the UK educational system filters out bad writers, whereas the US one does not.

Comment: @MWB my impression (having grown up in the US) is that the British system also places more emphasis on public speaking skills than does the US system.

Comment: "all intents and purposes" with the tendency of Americans to not enunciate the 'd' of and could sound like "all intensive purposes" if you're not familiar with the phrase, I guess. (me: American)

Comment: @ohwilleke what do you make of pronouncing the wrong form of the word “offence” in this video? https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mDD8flMdwTg&t=67s (see 1:07 and 1:20)

Comment: I think that @bdb484’s excellent answer demonstrates undeniably that it is possible to answer this question and that it’s not entirely subjective: there can certainly be objective and empirically testable factors at play.

Comment: I'd like to a see a video of a judge saying "intensive purposes". People who make this mistake probably hear the phrase, but never see it in writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The judges you're seeing on television are state-court judges, and state-court judges are -- for the most part -- politicians. They hold their offices because they got more votes than anyone else.

There is no requirement that they be smart, sophisticated, or scholarly. They and their speech patterns are somewhat naturally going to be reflective of the population at large.

The federal courts are populated with judges of a much higher caliber, but because there are no cameras in the courtrooms, you will not see them on television.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot tell you why you perceive what you do, but "sophistication" is in the eye of the beholder.

Someone unfamiliar with a dialect (such as any of the many American English dialects) could very well perceive "embarassing levels of unsophistication" while the "in" group sees nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Which dialect is "all intensive purposes" from? I'm not a native speaker, so I am not familiar with many dialects, and even the ones I *do* know are mostly stereotypes.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The phrase is "all intents and purposes" which I think OP misheard in the videos.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: it’s also a stock phrase

Comment: @jmoreno: That is interesting, I never knew that. I only know this phrase as an eggcorn, not a stock phrase. Do you have any sources?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: quick google yields https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/pardon-the-expression/all-intents-and-purposes-vs-all-intensive-purposes/#:~:text=The%20phrase%20for%20all%20intents,in%20any%20way%20he%20wished.

Comment: I would argue that “all intensive purposes” is the eggcorn, “all intents and purposes” is an empathetic version of “basically the same”. For all intents and purposes “Will no one rid me of this turbulent priest” was a command to kill.

Comment: It is somewhat common for people to mishear "for all intents and purposes" as "for all intensive purposes" due to the common reduction of "and" to a simpler sound (an "n" sound, typically) and then slurring it in with the preceding word within most American English.  E.g. "In-N-Out Burger" isn't just a stylized name, but an accurate reflection of a typical American pronunciation of "In and out". So common it is now relatively common for Americans to actually say and recognize the phrase as "for all intensive purposes".

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: all intensive purposes doesn't make any sense.   There is no such thing as intensive purpose. And substituting any of the synonyms yields nonsense. This question was the first I ever heard of anyone misunderstanding it. I don’t know of anyone that would mistake it.

Comment: @jmoreno Colloquialisms and turns of phrases and the evolution of language in general is not usually concerned with things such as "sense".  You make some noises, and if people feel like they understand what you meant by them and they like the idea of using those noises to convey much the the same thing, then they will parrot back and reuse them and then if enough people join the bandwagon it becomes part of the language.  In short, nonsense embiggens the dictionary.